# how to create a 2 dimensional field consisting of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

so i need to create a 2 dimensional field of pointers to a certain structure called "cell", and the function that does this needs to return a pointer for the whole thing.

but I get the following errors

1. dereferencing pointer to incomplete type at line 26 which is

   ```
   (*cell)->State = DEAD;
   ```
2. return from incompatible pointer type at line 30 which is :

   ```
   return kolommen;
   ```

Creating the field

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cell.h"

struct Cell ***allocate_field(int field_width, int field_height){
        struct Cell*** kolommen = malloc(field_width * sizeof *kolommen);

int i;
int j;

for(i=1;i == field_width;i++){
    kolommen[i] = malloc(field_width * sizeof (struct Cell**));
    for(j=1;j == field_height;j++){
        struct Cell *cell_pointer;
        kolommen[i][j] = malloc( sizeof (struct Cell*));
        kolommen[i][j] = cell_pointer;
        cell_pointer->state = 1;
    }
}
return kolommen;
```

cell

```
#ifndef CELL_H_
#define CELL_H_

enum Group {
    A, B
};

enum State {
    ALIVE, DEAD
};

struct Cell {
    enum Group group;
    enum State state;
};

#endif /* CELL_H_ */
```

Comment: Oh, dear [A Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: it's cell vs Cell...

Comment: Can you make up your mind if this is C or C++? For what it's worth  it really looks like plain C.

Comment: @BoPersson C'mon, if a 2D-"array" of pointers is needed that's the way to go.

Comment: @alk - But I bet the OP *really* needs a 2D array of cells. Like `std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>` if tagged [tag:C++].

Comment: haha these are pretty funny :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, this

```
struct cell*** kolommen = (struct cell***) malloc(field_width * sizeof(struct cell***));
```

should be

```
struct cell*** kolommen = malloc(field_width * sizeof(struct cell**));
```

and this

```
struct cell** rij = (struct cell**) malloc(field_width * sizeof(struct cell**));
```

should be

```
struct cell** rij = malloc(field_width * sizeof(struct cell*));
```

Mind the levels of indirection.

An even more flexible (and with this less error prone) approach would be:

```
struct cell*** kolommen = malloc(field_width * sizeof *kolommen);
```

and

```
 struct cell** rij = malloc(field_width * sizeof *rij);
```

---

Please note, that casting the result of `malloc()` & Friends is not needed, nor recommended in C.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from mixing use of `struct cell` with declaration of `struct Cell`. The `struct cell` is unknown and hence taken as an incomplete type (to an unknown struct). The other comments apply, too: There is a malloc missing to actually create the cells.

Plus, the lines

```
struct cell *cell;
(*cell)->State = DEAD;
```

are wrong because the `->` operator already performs an indirection. Therefore you either write

```
struct cell *cell;
// ... initialize the pointer somehow (missing in the original code)
cell->State = DEAD;
```

or

```
struct cell *cell; 
// init...
(*cell).State = DEAD;
```

The two are equivalent.

As a matter of style I find it confusing to name structs and variables alike, as `struct cell *cell;`, even though that is perfectly legal in C (struct "name tags" live in a distinct name space). In C++ the struct tag would introduce a type on its own which, I suppose, could lead to trouble if it's also used as a variable name. (But g++ compiles it just fine.)